# How to export/download more than 100k observations from Hue Impala?

Tags: hdfs, impala, hue

I am running a SQL select statement in Hue Impala and the results have around 300k rows which I want to download. Export to CSV or Excel is getting truncated at 100k observations. When I try to do an export to filebrowser directory I get a message that query failed. Basically results are not getting saved to the filebrowser directory.

How can I download or save to directory the results of my SELECT statement having more 300k rows?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls use impala shell -

```
impala-shell -B -o mytableoutput.csv --output_delimiter=',' -q "select * from mytable;"
```